# How do I get values entered in my Rails to form to remain after an error occurs in the form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, error-handling, model, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5.  I have a form with fields like the below

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  ...
  <div class="profileField">
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br/>
    <div class="field"><%= f.text_field :first_name, :size => 20, :class => 'textField', :tabIndex => '1' %></div>
  </div>
  ...

  <div class="profileField">
    Birthday <% if !@user.errors[:dob].empty? %><span class="profileError"> <%= @user.errors[:dob].join(', ') %></span><% end %> <br/> 
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.text_field :dob_string, :value => f.object.dob_string , :size => "20", :class => 'textField', placeholder: 'MM/DD/YYYY', :tabIndex => 1 %>
    </div>  
  </div>
```

When the form submits, it invokes this logic in my controller

```
  def update
    @user = current_user 
    @user.dob_string = user_params[:dob_string] 
    if !@user.errors.any? && @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      last_page_visited = session[:last_page_visited]  
      if !last_page_visited.nil? 
        session.delete(:last_page_visited) 
      else
        flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      end
      redirect_to !last_page_visited.nil? ? last_page_visited : url_for(:controller => 'races', :action => 'index') and return
    end

    @country_selected = !@user.address.nil? && !@user.address.country.nil? ? @user.address.country : Country.cached_find_by_iso('US')
    @states = @country_selected.states.sort_by {|obj| obj.name}      
    render 'edit'
  end
```

My question is, if there is an error in my form, how do I get the original values that someone entered before submitting the form to remain instead of the values that were previuosly saved?  Right now, if an error occurs, all the values the user previously entered are replaced by what was saved before.

**Edit:**

The solution didn't work.  I have a "dob" field (which is a PostGres DATE column), and hwen I entered an invalid value (e.g. "1234") and clicked "Save", everything saved without an error being thrown.  Below is my user model.  I also added the definition of my date field in my view.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :roles, through: :assignments
  belongs_to :address, :autosave => true  #, dependent: :destroy 

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address

  attr_accessor :dob_string 

  def dob_string
    @dob_string || (self.dob ? self.dob.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') : "")  
  end

  def dob_string=(dob_s)
    date = dob_s && !dob_s.empty? ? Date.strptime(dob_s, '%m/%d/%Y') : nil 
    self.dob = date
  rescue ArgumentError
    errors.add(:dob, 'The birth date is not in the correct format (MM/DD/YYYY)')
    @dob_string = dob_s
  end

  def role?(role)
    roles.any? { |r| r.name.underscore.to_sym == role.to_s.underscore.to_sym }
  end

  def admin?
    role? "Admin"
  end

  def name
    name = first_name 
    if !first_name.nil?
      name = "#{name} "
    end
    "#{name}#{last_name}" 
  end
```

Comment: from your code, if there is an error, `@user` should still have the values the user submitted.  the only way `@user` will have the old values is if `@user.errors.any?` is true and it doesn't reach the `@user.update_attributes` bit

Answer (score 0):

This will happen automatically if you load the attributes into the user slightly differently. the usual way to do it is something more like this:

```
def update
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
     # do stuff for when it saves correctly
  else
     # re-display the edit page with render :edit
```

Note: saving returns false if there are errors, so you don't need to check errors separately from this

But I see you're only letting them update the current user... (which is good). in which case you'll want:

```
def update
  @user = current_user
  # applies the attributes without saving to db
  @user.assign_attributes(user_params)
  if @user.save
     # do stuff for when it saves correctly
  else
     # re-display the edit page with render :edit
```

Doing either of these will allow the `@user` object to receive the attributes entered by the user - and that will then be passed to the `form` and be displayed.

Note: this assumes you are using something like `form_for @user` in your view (you didn't include that snippet)

Comment: When you say "if !@user.save", do you really mean "if @user.save"?  The lines directly after that are what should be executed when things are successful.

Comment: Hi, Even switching the logic to what I wrote above still results in issues, which I included in an edit to my question.

Comment: Dave. I don't (and can't) test the code I write... I also don't write literally what you should enter into your screen... what I write in an answer is a solution to the bug at hand... it's then up to you to make it actually work 100%. eg I deliberately didn't include the dob field because I figured you'd realise it was obvious that you should continue to include it in your code, and it just obscured the code that I was trying to write to show you the solution. Yes, you should add your dob code to the solution I gave you to make it actually fully work for you.

Comment: If this dob thing is a *new* error - ie not the error that you original reported in your original question... then you should create a new Question for it. It is a new question you are asking :)